# .net webservice needs to authenticate Android client

Tags: asp.net, android, authentication, ssl-certificate

I have Android app that talks to .net 2 webservice (IIS7) using http get and managed to make it run on https using self-signed server certificate (but not requiring client certificate).
I see all http traffic is encrypted and it looks secure.
Now what options would I have on how to authenticate client? For example, I like to block webservice access from internet explorer on PC.

Client-authenticated TLS handshake described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) would be a way to go? 
Then how can I accomplish that?  Some advice or example will be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of options, you might want to tell us who should be authenticated and who should not have access.

Comment: I like to block anonymous access from IE on PC. Android app user will be given some form of 'account' and webservice authenticates client to allow or deny access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, given that each user should authenticate anyhow, you probably want to setup some sort of per-user authentication strategy for a variety of reasons. First, given this might be a widely distributed app, having a single "gold master" authentication certificate or credentials will ultimately fail as someone will hack it -- either grabbing the cert or grabbing the account. And then what do you do? Second, its not particularly hard to handle. You can easily use ASP.NET membership to back it, and then take the credentials a number of ways depending on the nature of the service. Third, it is alot easier to manage than client certificates.

Comment: Thanks fro valid comment, Wyatt. I would turn my way to http basic access authentication or something else.

Comment: Wyatt, can you elaborate more about ASP.NET membership? I guess you are in asp.net side rather than Android. Authentication should be for non-windows users so none of IIS, ASP.NET authentication help me.